# No such file or directory after pod install

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

After researching this topic and trying different remedies this issue still persists. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/akgumyhdzqckesgeypelfxyqiggw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/My: No such file or directory
```

Iv'e checked the derived data folder, the file is there. I've tried numerous things like cleaning the project, deleting the derived data folder and running pod deintegrate/ pod install but to no avail.  The pods used to work before but after converting to Swift 3 they stopped.  One thing I noticed the project navigator setup looks different than another project I have that does currently work in swift 3 after a pod install. This is the one that doesn't work:

[image: error image]

This one does work:

[image: working]

Notice how the .app file is under the project folder in the one that doesn't work but appears in the pods folder in the one that does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the problem comes from you app name. See the error "Debug-iphonesimulator/My" : "MyShowGuide" is truncated

Be sure that "Product Name" under "Build Settings" is correct. Also, be sure to open .xcworkspace et no .xcodeproj

Comment: I've spent hours trying to figure this out and that fixed it, thanks!